# How to display / use a select value in an other tag with Angular 11 Material?

Tags: angular, select, tags, using

My problem is simple I think but I can't resolve it ! I want to use one or more selected values of a dropdown to display it / them in an other div tag.

I'm using Angular 11 Material.

I have a string list that I show in my dropdown like that ! [Here is the dropdown.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTj3Q.png)

Here is the code of the file.html.

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <h4> At event </h4>
      <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>Events</mat-label>
        <mat-select multiple [formGroup]="form">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let event of eventList" (click)="setIsAtEventChecked()" #eventChoosen [value]="event">
            {{ event }}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The #eventChoosen was supposed to be used to display the selected value in my html code here :

```
<div *ngIf="isAtEventChecked">
  <h3 class="text-left"> Description / Consequence at event "{{ eventChoosen.value }}" </h3>
  <app-event-add-description class="d-inline"></app-event-add-description>
</div>
```

But I have the error : `error TS2339: Property 'eventChoosen' does not exist on type 'EventAddTimerComponent'.`

I don't understand because I did something like that for my other variables.

Here is the code in my file.ts :

```
  public eventList: string[] = ["Open the door !", "Oh shit, here we go again !", "It's Johnny !",
"It's not a mine, it's a tomb! "];
```

I would like that my solution be like : [The solution that I would have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lcxbt.png)

Then, thank you so much for your help.

Regards,

Steven.

Comment: Have you ever used ViewChild?

Comment: I have no idea what it is. But if you want I can show you my entire html file ?

Comment: Search for ViewChild and you will have your answer.